# How to create Windows GUI application to play videos

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

This is the Code i am trying below.
I want to play .avi, .mp4, etc. 
I am able to select video but unable to play.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer

from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        videoWidget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()



        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(881, 578)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.widget = QVideoWidget(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(711, 471))
        self.widget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(711, 471))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 3, 1)
        self.audiobar = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.frame)
        self.audiobar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 160))
        self.audiobar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 160))
        self.audiobar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.audiobar.setObjectName("audiobar")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.audiobar, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.videobar = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.frame)
        self.videobar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(711, 22))
        self.videobar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(711, 22))
        self.videobar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.videobar.setObjectName("videobar")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.videobar, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 111))
        self.frame_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 111))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.playbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.playbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 75, 23))
        self.playbtn.setObjectName("playbtn")

        self.playbtn.setEnabled(False)

        self.pausebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pausebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pausebtn.setObjectName("pausebtn")
        self.stopbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.stopbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 75, 23))
        self.stopbtn.setObjectName("stopbtn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 881, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionClose = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose.setObjectName("actionClose")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)

        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.playbtn.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MPlayer"))
        self.playbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play"))
        self.pausebtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pause"))
        self.stopbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Video", " ", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.avi)",
                                                  QtCore.QDir.homePath())

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                   QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.playbtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.statusbar.showMessage(fileName)
            self.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the video output to `videoWidget`, but you didn't add it to the interface.

You already created a video widget, though, and it is `self.widget`, so you just have to use that (and only once):

```
    self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.widget)
```

Note that you are using the output of pyuic for your program, which is highly discouraged. Follow the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: Its working but unable to play .mp4 videos how to play .mp4 videos also.

Comment: @user3030327 what operating system are you using? If it is linux, you might need to install the related codecs for gstreamer.

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: @user3030327 It might still be necessary to install the required codecs (even if Windows' MediaPlayer is able to play them, it doesn't mean that Qt is). Try to run your program from the command prompt, if it says that the required plugin could not be found, than that's it. Have a look at [LAVFilters](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases)